# color boxes vs labels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I removed all the `input.*()` operator from the script to remove the Input tab in the Settings (Line 22 to 38).
When I did that, there are extra 2 color box showing -> Color 1, Color 2 [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/HkmnkLmD/color0.jpg).

I fix the Color 1, Color 2 boxes when I remove Labels scripts (line 125 to 152) [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/WpFNr8rn/fix.jpg).

Is there anyway to add label without compromising Color 0 box? I'm beginner in pinescript, please help.

Here is the whole script (before removing Labels)

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © cryptoweeknd

//@version=5
indicator("ADR", overlay=true)

//ADR side of script below

text_ADR1_high = 'ADR Upper'
text_ADR2_high = 'ADR Upper'

text_ADR1_low = 'ADR Lower'
text_ADR2_low = 'ADR Lower'

lime = #00FF00 //ADR2 Low
limes = #00FF00 //ADR1 Low
red = #FF4000 //ADR1 High
reds = #FF4000 //ADR2 High

//***Start of Inputs

labels_enabled = true

color_ADR1_high = red
color_ADR2_high = reds

color_ADR1_low = lime
color_ADR2_low = limes

adrUppercolorfill = red
adrlowercolorfill = lime
   
//***End of Inputs

//***Start of local functions definiton***

adr_1 = 10
adr_2 = 5

draw_line(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _xloc, _extend, _color, _style, _width) =>
    dline = line.new(x1=_x1, y1=_y1, x2=_x2, y2=_y2, xloc=_xloc, extend=_extend, color=_color, style=_style, width=_width)
    line.delete(dline[1])
    
draw_label(_x, _y, _text, _xloc, _yloc, _color, _style, _textcolor, _size, _textalign, _tooltip) =>
    dlabel = label.new(x=_x, y=_y, text=_text, xloc=_xloc, yloc=_yloc, color=_color, style=_style, textcolor=_textcolor, size=_size, textalign=_textalign, tooltip=_tooltip)
    label.delete(dlabel[1])

//If security is futures - replace the ticker with continuous contract
tickerid_func() =>
    tickerid = syminfo.tickerid
    if syminfo.type == 'futures'
        tickerid := syminfo.root + '1!'

//Function to calculate ADR levels
//Parameters:
//  * lengthInput - ADR period
//  * hi_low - true-->High, else-->Low 
adr_func(lengthInput,hi_low) =>
    float result = 0
    float adr = 0
    open_ = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr_High = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", ta.sma(high[1], lengthInput), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr_Low = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", ta.sma(low[1], lengthInput), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr := (adr_High - adr_Low)
    
    if hi_low//High
        result := adr/2 + open_
    else    //Low
        result := open_ - adr/2    

//Workaround to disable color management on the standard tab Style for plots
//Custom inputs for colors should be used instead
transp_func() =>
    transp_0 = 0

//***End of local functions definiton***

//***Start of getting data

start_time = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", time_close[1],barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)
open__ = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

start_time1 = request.security(tickerid_func(), "W", time_close[1],barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)

adr1_high = adr_func(adr_1,true)
adr1_low = adr_func(adr_1,false)
adr2_high = adr_func(adr_2,true)
adr2_low = adr_func(adr_2,false)

//***End of getting data

float _adr1_high = na
float _adr1_low = na
float _adr2_high = na
float _adr2_low = na
float _open = na

//*********************

//***Start of plotting*

//Decide if we can show the chart:
//Daily levels should be visible on intraday chart only

var show_chart = false

if timeframe.isintraday
    show_chart := true
    
//Plot all days
if show_chart
    _adr1_high := adr1_high
    _adr1_low  := adr1_low
    _adr2_high := adr2_high
    _adr2_low  := adr2_low
    _open      := open__

ADR1_high = plot(_adr1_high, title=text_ADR1_high, color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high, linewidth=1)
ADR2_high = plot(_adr2_high, title=text_ADR2_high, color=ta.change(_adr2_high) ? na : color_ADR2_high, linewidth=1)
ADR1_low = plot(_adr1_low, title=text_ADR1_low, color=ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color_ADR1_low, linewidth=1)
ADR2_low = plot(_adr2_low, title=text_ADR2_low, color=ta.change(_adr2_low) ? na : color_ADR2_low, linewidth=1)
fill(plot1 = ADR1_high, plot2 = ADR2_high, color = ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color.new(adrUppercolorfill, 80))
fill(plot1 = ADR1_low, plot2 = ADR2_low, color = ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color.new(adrlowercolorfill, 80))

//***Start of Labels***

label_ADR1_high = ''
label_ADR2_high = ''

label_ADR1_low = ''
label_ADR2_low = ''

if labels_enabled == true
    label_ADR1_high := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr1_high))
    label_ADR2_high := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr2_high))
    
    label_ADR1_low  := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr1_low))
    label_ADR2_low  := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr2_low))
        
string_ADR1_high = ' (' + label_ADR1_high + ')'
string_ADR2_high = ' (' + label_ADR2_high + ')'

string_ADR1_low = ' (' + label_ADR1_low + ')'
string_ADR2_low = ' (' + label_ADR2_low + ')'

//Labels
if show_chart and labels_enabled == true
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr1_high, text_ADR1_high + string_ADR1_high, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR1_high,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '') 
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr2_high, text_ADR2_high + string_ADR2_high, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR2_high,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')
  
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr1_low,  text_ADR1_low + string_ADR1_low, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR1_low,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')   
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr2_low,  text_ADR2_low + string_ADR2_low, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR2_low,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. If you use a mutable variable or user input as on/off switch, the label's color picker will be put into plot's color picker (and the label's color picker doesn't affect its color at all). I think it's actually a bug.

One workaround I tried would be putting the condition somewhere else, e.g.

before:

```
condition = input(true)
draw_label(...) =>
    dlabel = label.new(...)
    label.delete(dlabel[1])
if condition 
    draw_label(...)
```

after:

```
condition = input(true)
draw_label(...) =>
    if condition
        dlabel = label.new(...)
        label.delete(dlabel[1])
draw_label(...)
```

**Update 1**:
I try to find out what caused the bug, apparently in my code the user input didn't cause the bug.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ADR", overlay=true)
len1 = input(10)
len2 = input(5)
showlabel = input(true)

hclr = color.red
lclr = color.lime
tc = ta.change(time("D"))

drawlabel(level, clr) => label.delete(label.new(bar_index, level, str.tostring(level, format.mintick), color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=clr)[1])
adr(len) => ta.sma(ta.tr, len)

[adr1, adr2, C] = request.security("", "D", [adr(len1)[1], adr(len2)[1], close[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
h1 = C + adr1/2
h2 = C + adr2/2
l1 = C - adr1/2
l2 = C - adr2/2
h1p = plot(h1, color=tc?na:hclr)
h2p = plot(h2, color=tc?na:hclr)
l1p = plot(l1, color=tc?na:lclr)
l2p = plot(l2, color=tc?na:lclr)
fill(h1p, h2p, tc?na:color.new(hclr,80))
fill(l1p, l2p, tc?na:color.new(lclr,80))
if showlabel and timeframe.isintraday
    drawlabel(h1, hclr)
    drawlabel(h2, hclr)
    drawlabel(l1, lclr)
    drawlabel(l2, lclr)
```

**Update 2**:
Updated the code to fit your calculation. It's for testing purpose, I don't want to overcomplicate it. If you need to draw labels on each day, feel free to modify the code. Cheers.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ADR", overlay=true)
len1 = input(5)
len2 = input(10)
showlabel = input(true)

hclr = color.red
lclr = color.lime

drawlabel(level, clr) => label.delete(label.new(bar_index, level, str.tostring(level, format.mintick), color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=clr)[1])
adr(len) => ta.sma(high-low, len)

[adr1, adr2, O] = request.security("", "D", [adr(len1)[1], adr(len2)[1], open], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
h1 = O + adr1/2
h2 = O + adr2/2
l1 = O - adr1/2
l2 = O - adr2/2
tc = ta.change(O)
h1p = plot(h1, color=tc?na:hclr)
h2p = plot(h2, color=tc?na:hclr)
l1p = plot(l1, color=tc?na:lclr)
l2p = plot(l2, color=tc?na:lclr)
fill(h1p, h2p, tc?na:color.new(hclr,80))
fill(l1p, l2p, tc?na:color.new(lclr,80))
if showlabel and timeframe.isintraday
    drawlabel(h1, hclr)
    drawlabel(h2, hclr)
    drawlabel(l1, lclr)
    drawlabel(l2, lclr)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm new in tradingview pinescript code. Can you please tell which line I should add this `if condition` ?

Comment: Put `if show_chart and labels_enabled` into your `draw_label()` function. Also move `var show_chart = false` above the `draw_label()` declaration.

Comment: When I move `var show_chart = false` above the `draw_label()`, there is no issue. When I add `if show_chart and labels_enabled`, showing error `'dd to Chart operation failed, reason: line 46: Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'`. Modified lines are 44 to 46 [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/ncd63S2R/Untitled.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. You forgot to add indentation. It's a multi line function (just like your `tickerid_func()`), you'll need at least 1 indentation before the `if`. Read more about it here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html?highlight=indentation#multi-line-functions

Comment: Thanks for helping me mate. it's done. but it didn't hide Color 1, Color 2 boxes. [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/1RDw5d48/Untitled-1.jpg)

Comment: Did you remove this line: `if show_chart and labels_enabled == true` at the end of your script?

Comment: Just did it. You are a life saver mate. [Screenshot](https://postimg.cc/LJKc443V). There are few more questions about the script. Hope you help on that too.

Comment: Sure. Please open a new question for that. But before you do that, I just updated my answer with my attempt of replicating your indicator. You can use my code if you find it easier to maintain.

Comment: Your code is very clean and simple. I going to use that. But the ADR levels are not correct with my levels [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/4xz7drwR/2.jpg). And can you please give label ADR Upper, ADR Lower plot for all days? Sorry for your time

Comment: please check my new question