# create label with values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to add labels (S1, R1 etc) with values on this script for all days like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/GmgyY971/Untitled-1.jpg) **or** change along with the line color? I tried to example `draw_label` function from other pinescripts, but all have some difference so ended up error.
I'm not good at scripting. Anyone help please.

Here is the script.

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © pbghosh

//@version=5
indicator(title='Daily CPR', shorttitle='D-CPR', overlay=true, format=format.price, precision=2)

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
c = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

notHigherTimeframe = timeframe.period != '30' and timeframe.period != '45' and timeframe.period != '60' and timeframe.period != '120' and timeframe.period != '180' and timeframe.period != '240' and timeframe.period != 'D' and timeframe.period != 'W' and timeframe.period != 'M'

calculatePivot() =>
    (h + l + c) / 3

calculateBC() =>
    (h + l) / 2

calculateTC() =>
    calculatePivot() - calculateBC() + calculatePivot()

truncate(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    int(number * factor) / factor
    //round(number * 10) / 10

pivot = calculatePivot()
tc = calculateTC()
bc = calculateBC()

if tc < bc
    t = tc
    tc := bc
    bc := t
    bc

r1Level = truncate(2 * pivot - l, 2)
r2Level = truncate(pivot + h - l, 2)
r3Level = truncate(h + 2 * (pivot - l), 2)
r4Level = truncate(h + 3 * (pivot - l), 2)
r5Level = truncate(h + 4 * (pivot - l), 2)
s1Level = truncate(2 * pivot - h, 2)
s2Level = truncate(pivot - (h - l), 2)
s3Level = truncate(l - 2 * (h - pivot), 2)
s4Level = truncate(l - 3 * (h - pivot), 2)
s5Level = truncate(l - 4 * (h - pivot), 2)

plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(tc, 2) : na, title='TC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(pivot, 2) : na, title='CP', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(bc, 2) : na, title='BC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r1Level : na, title='R1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #32cd32, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s1Level : na, title='S1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #ff3030, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r2Level : na, title='R2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #32cd32, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s2Level : na, title='S2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #ff3030, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r3Level : na, title='R3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #32cd32, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s3Level : na, title='S3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #ff3030, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r4Level : na, title='R4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #32cd32, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r5Level : na, title='R5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #32cd32, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s4Level : na, title='S4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #ff3030, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s5Level : na, title='S5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #ff3030, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? h : na, title='PDH', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? l : na, title='PDL', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot the indicator is not using labels, it's using `plotchar()`, which only displays constant string. If you want to display values dynamically, you'd want to use labels, not `plotchar()`.

Comment: The screenshot indicator have labels. It is a protected script from the owner. Here is the [link](https://www.tradingview.com/v/EK1nqR79/)

Comment: As I said, those "P" "S1" "R1" are not labels, but `text` parameter from `plotchar()`. If it's using labels, you should see "Labels" with a checkbox under the Style tab where you can hide the labels.

Comment: The main script (CPR) didn't have label function. Original [link](https://in.tradingview.com/script/KlyvRAxz-Daily-CPR/). But I tried to add labels like [ADR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488661/color-boxes-vs-labels) script and also from your reply. Both didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad mate. I want lables. not text. that we can hide with the "Labels"checkbox.

Comment: It seems you wanted the ADR + CPR script with labels showing dynamic numbers while color can be changed under Style tab. Am I right? If I'm right, I'm afraid it's not possible, as label color can only be changed through user input AFAIK.

Comment: Yes it is right. But if we can change it along with the line colour, it is ok even there is input tab.

Comment: what is the `text parameter` function for creating text label?

Comment: The Manual explains it pretty well, it should also help you with labels, take a look: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html

Comment: mate, can you please give example for first plot? I'll try to do the rest.

Comment: `plotchar(timeframe.change("D"), text="S1")` The `text` argument here sets to "S1", this line will plot a star and "S1" each time a new day starts.

Comment: When I add `plotchar` fuction all [labels](https://i.postimg.cc/qvT8kk87/Untitled-2.jpg), labels are displayed in one [location](https://i.postimg.cc/QNJYLyL1/Untitled-1.jpg). Why it doesn't show it to the corresponed line?

Comment: You'll need to specify the location parameter,  e.g. `plotchar(timeframe.change("D")?truncate(tc, 2):na, location=location.absolute, text="TC")`

Comment: Thanks mate. [Fixed](https://i.postimg.cc/MpXK2yHR/fix.jpg). But I have a doubt. In [ADR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488661/color-boxes-vs-labels) script, you use `drawlabel` function (line 26 to 29) in Update 1 & Update 2. How didn't that work this script?

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to use `plotchar()` since that's how the ADR + CPR script is implemented. Labels do work, as I said, if you want to display dynamic values, you'll have to use labels.

Comment: can you send me the function code for `drawlabel`? I tried copy `drawlable` from ADR but it didn't work (line 26 to 29)

Comment: ? It should. Please show me what you did so far.

Comment: You can update your question with your code, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Here is the `drawlabel` added [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k8Mxud0K48eKebpr6_GbZDeSL1WFTyLN/view?usp=sharing).  This is the [error.](https://i.postimg.cc/8cK9Xx0M/ERROR.jpg)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you didn't declare `showlabel` and `drawlabel()` in the script. You need to copy these two lines as well: `showlabel = input(true)
drawlabel(level, color) => label.delete(label.new(bar_index, level, str.tostring(level, format.mintick), color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color)[1])
` prior to that block.

Comment: Thanks you, [fixed](https://i.postimg.cc/2yKgGdn8/values.jpg). Last question. It is showing only line values. Not showing Line labels. I tries to use `title='TC' ` in `drawlabel(truncate(tc, 2), title='TC', color.blue) ` but it didn't work. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19IKrH8Ox9xQuCHHnUhvf6Z7QOPqFvmdr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There's no title parameter for the drawlabel function. This might be what you want: change the drawlabel declaration to: `drawlabel(level, title, color) => label.delete(label.new(bar_index, level, title + ": " + str.tostring(level, format.mintick), color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color)[1])`.

Comment: when added new declaration showing [error.](https://i.postimg.cc/VNrTHqVs/Untitled-1.jpg) Here is the modified [script.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDOSLbN4YArmrRMPOHKA9Hr7usRWKqi4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your code has once again triggered a weird bug... I don't know why, but it seems you'll have to use `color=color.blue` instead of just `color.blue`, or just don't use parameter names at all. e.g. change `drawlabel(r2Level, title='R2', color=#FF4000)` to `drawlabel(r2Level, 'R2', #FF4000)`

Comment: hi, can you please help me [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647222/unable-to-see-levels-after-plots-variables-grouped)

Comment: Have you figured it out?